# How can i make dependencies between list/map/class(?) items in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an idea to an app I'm making, that I'd like to make possible, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what the solution should be.

Basically I need to be able to make instances/items of something (class?, map?), and I want to be able to refer some of these items to each other, like a dependency. I imagine, that I could make a new item, tell it that itemX is its "parent", while itemX is told that new item is its "child".

Something like:

```
item1

item2

item3 --> item4 --> item5

item6 --> item7

**
```

At the same time I want to be able to list the items, sorting them in different ways;

all items that don't have children

all children of an item

parent of an item

sorted by a date that was passed to them

etc.

Also I want the user to be able to add or delete items without the dependencies breaking, e.g. `item[4]` becoming `item[3]` when deleting `item[2]`, causing an item to switch parent or child.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Will a particular item have not more than on child and not more than one parent?

Comment: Could have more, especially children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link items to items in class

```
class Item {
   // other class members

   List<Item> _children = []; //list of children of type item 
   List<Item> _parents = [];  //list of parent of type item   

   Item();        

   List<Item> get getChildren => _children;
   List<Item> get getParents => _parents;

   set setChildren(Item child){
      _children.add(child);  
      //passing instance of item to this item.
   }
   set setParents(Item parent){
      _parents.add(parent);
   }

   //other methods

}
```

Then you can use something like:

```
let itemA = new Item();
let itemB = new Item();

itemA.setChildren(itemB);
itemB.setParents(itemA);

print(itemA.getChildren()); // [itemB]
print(itemB.getChildren()); // []
print(itemB.getParents()); // [itemA]
```

Comment: Appreciate it :)
Will I be able to find and list all instances of this class?